# Index/Match with ListObject (Table)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to know the index number for a certain name, for example when I write in TextBox1 = Sara, and click the button,
Then TextBox2 should return index value opposite to that name in the table (Table1)

[image]

I tried INDEX/Match method on cell sheet, and it worked, but i tried translating it to a vba code, but I get msgbox saying

> Run time 1004 Unable to get the match property of the worksheetFunction class.

my code was

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
TextBox2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet1.tbl.ListColumns(1), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(TextBox1.Value, tbl.ListColumns(2), 0), 1)
End Sub
```

I want TextBox2 to return the index number on the table, If I write "Sam" on TextBox1, then TextBox2 should show 3.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match) and nothing matches it throws an exception. That is probably what you get.

So always use it like this:

```
Dim MatchedRowNumber As Double
On Error Resume Next 'hide the exception
MatchedRowNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(TextBox1.Value, tbl.ListColumns(2), 0)
On Error Goto 0 'always directly re-activate error reporting!!!

If MatchedRowNumber > 0 Then 'the row number will be 0 if nothing matched
    Dim LookupValue As String
    LookupValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet1.tbl.ListColumns(1), MatchedRowNumber, 1)
    TextBox2.Value = LookupValue 
Else
    MsgBox "No match!"
End If
```

---

The altertative would be to use the `Application.Match` function instead of `WorksheetFunction.Match`:

```
Dim MatchedRowNumber As Double
MatchedRowNumber = Application.Match(TextBox1.Value, tbl.ListColumns(2), 0)

If Not IsError(MatchedRowNumber) Then 
    Dim LookupValue As String
    LookupValue = Application.Index(Sheet1.tbl.ListColumns(1), MatchedRowNumber, 1)
    TextBox2.Value = LookupValue 
Else
    MsgBox "No match!"
End If
```

While `WorksheetFunction.Match` throws an exception, `Application.Match` instead returns an error value that you can test with the [IsError function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iserror-function).

Comment: You could wrap the expression with the `IsError`-Function, so you don't have to hide exceptions.

Comment: @MarcoGetrost No you cannot. The `WorksheetFunction.Match` will throw an exception that cannot be handled by the `IsError` function. • You probably mixed up `WorksheetFunction.Match` with `Application.Match` (this one returns an error value and does not throw an exception).

Comment: @MarcoGetrost See updated answer, which now covers both approaches.